# jQuery Siblings Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have created a Responsive Sub-Menu for a Responsive Website that actives at equal to or less than 768px. I have it set up to where jQuery removes the link for the Parent List Item and displays the sub-menu onClick.

The problem is, there is a Parent that has no children and I am trying to only remove the link(href) of Parent Elements that do have children. But, I even applied it in an If statement so it wouldn't remove the parent link if it has no children, that didn't work. So I tried siblings, which I thought would make more sense. But it is still not behaving as so.

Here is my jQuery for this:

```
    if (jQuery(".navigation > ul > li > a").siblings("ul")){
        jQuery(".navigation > ul > li > a").removeAttr("href");
    };
```

You may see an example here: http://stlredtails.com/construction/

Edit: The Contact link is the link that has no "ul" children, practical terms, there is no sub-menu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your if statement always returns true and your following command removes the href attribute from all matched elements. you will need to loop through the matching anchors and process an if statement for each one.

```
jQuery(".navigation > ul > li > a").each( function() {
    if(jQuery(this).siblings("ul").length) {
        jQuery(this).removeAttr("href");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand what you are asking, but it sounds like you may be in need of jQuery's `:empty` and/or `:parent` selectors.

Try something like:

```
$(".navigation > ul:parent > li > a")
```

[jQuery :empty documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

[jQuery :parent documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

> jQuery Siblings Not Working?

It is working. Yet it always evaluates to a jQuery wrapper *object* even if it matched nothing, and that value is truthy so your if-block always executes. Check for the `.length`-property to be not `0`.

> I have it set up to where jQuery removes the link for the Parent List Item and displays the sub-menu onClick.

There is absolutely no reason to remove the `href` attribute. To prevent following the link even if you clicked ("activated") it, call [`preventDefault()` on the event object](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the `click` event handler!